# Social authentication with (spring boot, Angular 7+)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-social

I want to start full stack project with Angular and Spring boot and I want download project for start from him,
The project must have(Login, Signup) with social authentication like(Facebook,Google,LinkedIn ...etc).
If there is anybody has sample of the project that have these features please sharing .

This picture similar what I want:

---

[image]